# Menus under Menus

Tags: buttons, menu, web, hierarchy

how do people feel about menus within other menus? I have the top menu which distinguishes between Individual Students and Groups, then the group name. 
And THEN two sections which how the students in that group and assignments for that group. Is this the best way to display this to the user?

[image]

[image: this is the full screen. This is for a website. The "add" icon on the left is to add a user.]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Is this desktop, mobile? What are the other elements on the screen? What's the icon to the left? Add a user? The more details you can show us, the more the feedback may be useful.

Comment: Also, this looks more like segmented controls, acting as a filter.

Comment: @MikeM please see above, added the whole screenshot. This is for web. the "add user" icon on the left is to add a student to the group. Hope this provides the context.

Comment: I'm confused, aside from detaching "Students" & "Assignments" from the top menu, it's a simple nested menu.

Answer (score 1):

Menus under Menus or Nested Menus can be a bad UI but a good UX when it helps users to easily navigate to their goals/desired information.

You are here using tabs for - Individuals and Groups. Then, in the Groups Tab, you might show a list of groups or dropdown of groups. The user can choose the group and be presented with corresponding info.

The layout for group's info can be done based on selection or you can creatively display students and assignments together on screen if that's an option. Otherwise, you could use Radio buttons, nested tabs for showing Students or Assignments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. its awesome! However one concern i have is that when a user first looks at this, they would not readily know who to access the assignments part. until they go to the drop down. Which may not be a big deal...but just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is not a good design because

1. You can't handle multiple records under one topic. Such as how can you express if the number of groups is more than one.
2. I feel that data is not well-arranged.

I think you can use tabs for this situation, My suggestion as follows,

1. Divide the screen into two by horizontal line.
2. Add two tabs into the upper section and name them as "INDIVIDUAL" and "GROUPS"
3. Now add two tabs for the latter section of the screen also.
4. Name them as "STUDENTS" and "ASSIGNMENTS".

Now you can load the below tabs and table according to the upper tab selection

Comment: thanks. i thought that was exactly what i had done in my picture above?  main menu and then a sub menu...